# How to make my product decrement instead of increment?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created an e-commerce website in html/css/javascript, i have a problem with the decrementation, when i click on "-" to remove the price of the product it keeps incrementing the price in the cart when it should decrement it.

var cartTotal = 0;

```
    function addToCart(button, price) {
        var quantity = parseInt(button.parentElement.querySelector("span").textContent);
        var totalForProduct = quantity * price;
        cartTotal += totalForProduct;

        var productName = button.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("h3").textContent;
        var cartList = document.getElementById('cartList');

        var existingCartItem = cartList.querySelector('[data-product-name="' + productName + '"]');
        if (existingCartItem) {
            var existingQuantity = parseInt(existingCartItem.querySelector('.cart-item-quantity').textContent);
            existingQuantity += quantity;
            existingCartItem.querySelector('.cart-item-quantity').textContent = existingQuantity;

            var existingTotal = parseInt(existingCartItem.querySelector('.cart-item-total').textContent);
            existingTotal += totalForProduct;
            existingCartItem.querySelector('.cart-item-total').textContent = existingTotal;
        } else {
            var cartItem = document.createElement('li');
            cartItem.classList.add('cart-item');
            cartItem.setAttribute('data-product-name', productName);
            cartItem.innerHTML =
                productName + ' (' + price + ' lei) x <span class="cart-item-quantity">' + quantity + '</span> = <span class="cart-item-total">' + totalForProduct + '</span> lei' +
                '<button onclick="removeFromCart(this)">Șterge</button>';
            cartList.appendChild(cartItem);
        }

        document.getElementById('total').textContent = cartTotal;
    }

    function removeFromCart(button) {
        var cartItem = button.parentElement;
        var totalForProduct = parseInt(cartItem.querySelector('.cart-item-total').textContent);
        cartTotal -= totalForProduct;
        document.getElementById('total').textContent = cartTotal;
        cartItem.remove();
    }

    function changeQuantity(button, change) {
        const quantityElement = button.parentElement.querySelector("span");
        const quantity = parseInt(quantityElement.textContent);

        if (change === -1 && quantity > 0) {
            quantityElement.textContent = quantity - 1;
        } else if (change === 1) {
            quantityElement.textContent = quantity + 1;
        }
    }

    function clearCart() {
        var cartList = document.getElementById('cartList');
        cartList.innerHTML = '';
        cartTotal = 0;
        document.getElementById('total').textContent = cartTotal;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the subtraction part of your code in the changeQuantity function. You are lowering the quantity, but the total price in the addToCart function still uses the original quantity. Just update the total price when decreasing the quantity to fix this :)